# Laravel: Refactoring Controller store() and update() methods

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, refactoring

I'm developing a Laravel Web App and I need insight in refactoring my Controller.

I noticed that my Controller store() and update() methods are VERY similiar. So similar that the only line that changes are the following:
In the store() method I use `$deck = new Deck();` and in the update() method I use `$deck = Deck::find($id);`. These are the only lines that change in these 140 line each methods inside the Controller.

How can I refactor or to where should I extract this code? My first thought was to create a Trait and put the method there, but that doesn't seem right, or does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't advise on using a single method for both, but not knowing your use case you can use the `firstOrNew` helper method, which will return the `Deck` if it exists by the id given or it will make a new instance for you. So use this:

```
Deck::firstOrNew(['id' => $id]);
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about this method. And where should I keep the extracted body from store() and update()?

Comment: @PietroBonfim do you have a different body for both methods? I thought you want to use one method only that will match both.. If that's not the case just extract a function and call it passing the `$deck` from both methods.

Comment: No, I'd keep both methods in the controller, only extract the logic inside them, which only differs by those 2 lines.

Comment: Okay, create a private function in the controller, and call it from both methods. :) you can accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: But do you have a suggestion on where I should put the extracted logic from store() and update()? Inside a trait, inside the controller itself....?

Comment: I edited my answer on the comment above. I would put it in a private method in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the application logic in your controller, you can make a function to your duplicate code, then pass the Deck object in the parameter.

```
  public function store()
  {
    $deck = new Deck();
    $this->save($deck);
  }

  public function update()
  {
    Deck::find($id);
    $this->save($deck);
  }

  private function save(Deck $deck)
  {
    // Duplicate Code goes here
  }
```

I hope I've helped

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to keep it simple. I would create a private function with the duplicated code and call it from store() and update() functions.

Comment: Inside the controller itself?

Comment: Well, I am not sure how you are planning to organize it. It could be in another class where you can write your MVC business logic, or in the controller itself. Software Design Principles DRY and KISS. ;)